# Showing that for $a > 0$ fixed that $\{(\theta, a\theta^2): \theta> 0\}$ is not an open set

Tags: general-topology

This is going to be a bit difficult, as I'm having to gather the definition of an open set from non-prerequisite courses. (The course I'm taking is a mathematical statistics course requiring Calculus III and Linear Algebra.) But here's my attempt.

> Show that for $a > 0$ fixed that $\{(\theta, a\theta^2): \theta > 0\}$ is not an open set.

Intuitively, this makes sense, as the set given above are just the points that are on a parabola in $\mathbb{R}_{>0} \times \mathbb{R}_{>0}$, and thus we can't enclose a rectangular neighborhood around it.

Denote $\Theta = \{(\theta, a\theta^2): \theta > 0\}$. Fix $\theta_0 > 0$ and $a_0 > 0$ so that $\mathbf{x} = (\theta_0, a_0\theta_0^2) \in \Theta$. Suppose, by contradiction, that $\Theta$ were open. Then there would exist a $\delta > 0$ such that 
$$\mathcal{Y} = \{(y_1, y_2): \sqrt{(\theta_0-y_1)^2+(a_0\theta_0^2-y_2)^2}<\delta\} \subset\Theta\text{.}$$
So, thus, what I need to do is find some $\delta$ which would lead me to contradicting the $\subset$ statement above. Can someone provide a hint for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your solution, when you suppose for the sake of contradiction that $\Theta$ is open, once you fix $a_0$ and $\theta_0$ the definition of open set provides you with a $\delta$. Thus $\delta$ is fixed, but you can (for instance) take $y_2 = a_0\theta_0^2$ and $y_1 = \theta_0 + \frac{\delta}{2}$.  Then $(y_1,y_2) \in \cal Y$, yet $$(\theta_0 + \frac{\delta}{2}, a_0 \theta_0^2) \notin \Theta.$$

Comment: Ah, the reason why we can choose particular values for $y_1$ and $y_2$  is because our proof by contradiction says that $\mathcal{Y} \subset \Theta$ for ANY $y_1, y_2 \in \mathbb{R}$, as long as the Euclidean norm condition is satisfied, correct?

Comment: That's right! Any $(y_1,y_2) \in \cal Y$ must also belong to $\Theta$.