# Showing that for $a > 0$ fixed that $\{(\theta, a\theta^2): \theta> 0\}$ does not contain an open set

Tags: general-topology

This appears to be a near-duplicate of [Showing that for $a > 0$ fixed that $\{(\theta, a\theta^2): \theta> 0\}$ is not an open set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2184817/showing-that-for-a-0-fixed-that-theta-a-theta2-theta-0-is-not/2184829#comment4494459_2184829), but as you can see from [Containing an open set = being an open set?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2184858/containing-an-open-set-being-an-open-set), I clearly thought that showing that for $a > 0$ fixed $\Theta = \{(\theta, a\theta^2): \theta > 0\} \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ not being open was sufficient to be finished with this problem, which (likely) isn't the case. So I am going to rephrase this question to what I'm actually looking for:

> Show that for $a > 0$ fixed that $\Theta = \{(\theta, a\theta^2): \theta > 0\}$ **does not contain** an open set.

**Sketch Attempt**: Suppose, by way of contradiction, that there exists a $\Theta^{\prime} \subset \Theta$ which is open. Then $\Theta^{\prime}$ contains some open rectangles. However, $\Theta$ doesn't contain any open rectangles, as all of its points lie on a parabola in $\mathbb{R}_{> 0} \times \mathbb{R}_{> 0}$. Thus, $\Theta$ does not contain an open set.

How do I formalize the above?

Comment: What kind of formalism do you have in mind?

Comment: @uniquesolution I'm not satisfied with the "parabola" statement... or maybe the proof is good as it is? As I've mentioned in previous questions, I'm not familiar with topology.

Comment: The goodness of a proof depends on its audience, of course :)

Comment: @uniquesolution Let's assume that you're in an introductory topology course and you've learned about the definition of an open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Would the above proof be satisfactory?

Comment: How to formalize: For every point $M$ in $\Theta$ and every positive $\epsilon$, the point $M+\epsilon(0,1)$ is at distance $\epsilon$ from $M$ and is not in $\Theta$, qed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elements of $\Theta$ satisfy the polynomial equation $y-ax^2=0$. Suppose $U\subseteq \Theta$ is a non-empty open set. In particular, there are two infinite subsets $S_1,S_2\subseteq \Bbb R$ such that $S_1\times S_2\subseteq U\subseteq\Theta$, id est, such that $y-ax^2=0$ for all $x\in S_1$ and for all $y\in S_2$. But this would mean, in particular, that for a fixed $x_0\in S_1$ the equation $y-ax_0^2=0$ is satisfied by infinitely many $y$. Absurd.