# Question on completeness of sufficient statistic.

Tags: statistical-inference, parameter-estimation

Let $X_1,X_2,X_3....X_n$ be a sample from density $N(\theta,\theta^2)$ then the statistic $T=(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i,\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2)$ is sufficient how do i check for completness in two dimensional space? I don't know how to to compute $E(g(x))=0$. Please someone tell me.

Comment: Note that $N(\theta, \theta^2)$ is of the exponential family. How my professor taught this is that you need to show that you need to show that the parameter space $(\theta, \theta^2)$ contains an open set: then it would follow that $T$ would be complete and sufficient (I haven't seen the proof of this). But - I think if you think about it intuitively, you'll see that it doesn't - I expect that $T$ may be sufficient, but it won't be complete.

Comment: @Clarinetist you have to really help me in this i am really having bad time understanding completeness. Please tell me thoroughly about this. I didn't understand what does open set mean here.

Comment: It's been about a year since I've seen this material (I'm honestly surprised I could figure out your last question). But you should see [this question I asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2184888/showing-that-for-a-0-fixed-that-theta-a-theta2-theta-0-does-no); simply use $a = 1$. I don't remember much beyond this.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/i3x0z0 This question here got dow voted i don't know why may be i gave bad reasoning of it. Let me know i ll put it again if you will answer that. Two dimensional completeness is really giving me headache sir . I am not able to understand it.